# Scons finds invalid syntax in gpsd

Tags: linux, scons, gpsd

I'm trying to install gpsd from http://developer.berlios.de/project/showfiles.php?group_id=2116 but when I run scons on the folder I get:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
File "/root/gpsd/gpsd-3.0/SConstruct", line 290

with open("xmltest.xml", "w") as ofp:

        ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? Seems like it's too old.

Comment: 2.4, I'm waiting to install 2.7 on centos, then Ill update the question with the solution (probably that 2.4 doesnt have the with statement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated to a python 2.7 and it works.